# Can I make Python output exceptions in one line / via logging?

Tags: python, logging, traceback, python-logging

I am using AWS and use AWS cloudwatch to view logs. While things should not break on AWS, they could. I just had such a case. Then I searched for `Traceback` and just got the lines

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

without the actual traceback. I have a working structured logging setup (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202500/562769)) and I would like to get tracebacks in a similar way.

So instead of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/math/Desktop/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    adf
NameError: name 'adf' is not defined
```

something like

```
{"message": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n      File \"/home/math/Desktop/test.py\", line 32, in <module>\n        adf\n    NameError: name 'adf' is not defined", "lineno": 35, "pathname": "/home/math/Desktop/test.py"}
```

or even better also with the string in a JSON format.

The only way to achieve this I can think of is a giant try-except block. Pokemon-style. Is there a better solution?

Comment: So you don't want a try except block and also want to log errors with formatted way?

Comment: You should use a custom [`logging.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) and implement `formatException`.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). It is invoked whenever an exception occurs in your script.

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback

def exception_logging(exctype, value, tb):
    """
    Log exception by using the root logger.

    Parameters
    ----------
    exctype : type
    value : NameError
    tb : traceback
    """
    write_val = {'exception_type': str(exctype),
                 'message': str(traceback.format_tb(tb, 10))}
    logging.exception(str(write_val))
```

Then in your script you have to override the value of `sys.excepthook`.

```
sys.excepthook = exception_logging
```

Now whenever an exception occurs it will be logged with your logger handler.

Note: Don't forget to setup logger before running this

Comment: I'm trying this with my django application...any idea where to place it, codewise? I'm trying a `apps.py` and `AppConfig`, using `ready()` to override the `sys.excepthook`. As seen in the following link, logging is setup quite early, so, before ready....but no look, still many lines...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody wants the exception logged in its default format, but in one line (for any reason), based on the accepted answer:

```
def exception_logging(exctype, value, tb):
    """
    Log exception in one line by using the root logger.

    Parameters
    ----------
    exctype : exception type
    value : seems to be the Exception object (with its message)
    tb : traceback
    """
    logging.error(''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb)))
```

Please also note, that it uses logging.error() instead of logging.exception() which also printed some extra "NoneType: None" line.
Also note that it only seems to work with uncaught exceptions.
For logging caught exceptions, visit [How do I can format exception stacktraces in Python logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180159/how-do-i-can-format-exception-stacktraces-in-python-logging) and see also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation: If you run a Flask application, you can do this:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def exception_logger(error):
    """Log the exception."""
    logger.exception(str(error))
    return str(error)
```